# How to post a multipart form data using node to a rails backend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js

Node uses code like this to submit a multipart form data:

```
var form = new FormData();

form.append(project.name+'.zip', fs.createReadStream("/"+project.name+'.zip'));
form.submit({
    host: 'http://host.mysite.dev',
    path: '/api/v1/prototypes',
    headers: {
      'Authentication': 'secret'
    }
  }, function(err, res) {
    if(err) console.log("ERR: ", err)
    else console.log("RES: ", res)
    console.log(res.statusCode);
  });
```

My backend is expecting the request to look like this (tested with postman).

```
------WebKitFormBoundarywo69VE86H8vMc9ah
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachment"; filename="basic.zip"
Content-Type: application/zip


------WebKitFormBoundarywo69VE86H8vMc9ah--
```

Instead, my request looks like this crazy gibberish which rails can't interpret. I have no idea how to make a normal multipart form request with node.

```
{
"attachment":{
  "_overheadLength":157,
  "_valueLength":0,
  "_lengthRetrievers":[
     null
  ],
  "writable":false,
  "readable":true,
  "dataSize":0,
  "maxDataSize":2097152,
  "pauseStreams":true,
  "_released":false,
  "_streams":[
     "----------------------------860185489573893683941879\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"app.zip\"; filename=\"app.zip\"\r\nContent-Type: application-zip\r\n\r\n",
   {
        "source":{
           "_readableState":{
              "objectMode":false,
              "highWaterMark":65536,
              "buffer":[
                 {
                    "type":"Buffer",
                    "data":[
                       80,
                       181
                    ]
                 }
              ],
              "length":65536,
              "pipes":null,
              "pipesCount":0,
              "flowing":false,
              "ended":false,
              "endEmitted":false,
              "reading":false,
              "sync":false,
              "needReadable":false,
              "emittedReadable":true,
              "readableListening":false,
              "defaultEncoding":"utf8",
              "ranOut":false,
              "awaitDrain":0,
              "readingMore":false,
              "decoder":null,
              "encoding":null
           },
           "readable":true,
           "domain":null,
           "_events":{

           },
           "_eventsCount":3,
           "path":"/Users/guest/Library/Application Support/foundation-apps-template/app.zip",
           "fd":299,
           "flags":"r",
           "mode":438,
           "autoClose":true
        },
        "dataSize":0,
        "maxDataSize":null,
        "pauseStream":true,
        "_maxDataSizeExceeded":false,
        "_released":false,
        "_bufferedEvents":[

        ],
        "_events":{

        },
        "_eventsCount":1
     },
     null
  ],
  "_currentStream":null,
  "_boundary":"--------------------------860185489573893683941879"
 }
}
```

I don't know what to do to either A. Parse this crazy packet (which I don't know how to do). or B. get it to look like a normal multipart form submission. I've been stuck with this problem for 3 work days and I've tried a lot of things, none of which have worked. I'm starting to get desperate to figure this out. I'm ready to give up on all of this and start assembling my packet from scratch - not sure how to do that either though. But at this point it couldn't be any harder than trying to make this nonsense work.

Comment: Are you sure you're allowed to dump an arbitrary file stream into `append()`? The documentation implies you can but you're seeing the raw JavaScript object here.

Comment: Not trying to make you read documentation... but here is a link to their example of the multipart form data https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data. They dump the arbitrary file stream into append as I did. Unfortunately not a single one of the examples goes over parsing the request you send back into a file.

Comment: I was just looking at that and it *should* work, but what you're seeing here is being treated as a dumb JavaScript object (internals of the stream) and not the stream data properly encoded. From their docs: `form.append('my_file', fs.createReadStream('/foo/bar.jpg'));`.

Comment: Is it possible to turn it into a file once it reaches the rails backend, or is it not possible due to the malformed (not properly encoded as you said) nature of this request? 

If it isn't possible to resolve this on the back end.... Do you think just assembling my packet body from scratch could solve my problem? I have tried a lot of node packages and all of them seem to stream it just like I have shown here.

Comment: If that's what you're seeing on the Rails side, it's too late. You need to have a properly encoded POST request and there's no way to reconstitute it from that, especially considering your Rails process can't go and access random files on other computers. Are you sure that's the request being made? Can you run this through a capturing proxy tool?

Comment: That information is invaluable - I would have spent a lot of time trying to fix it on the rails end. I will keep working on the post request itself then.

Comment: Yeah, seeing file paths leak out onto the Rails side is a sign that Node.js wasn't finished with the request and it was sent incorrectly, presuming that last bit is what Rails is seeing and not just a dump of your Node object.

Comment: If you put an answer down with some of your comments I'd be happy to give you the best answer. I now have information to move forward which is what I really needed.

Comment: It's just a hypothesis at this point. Let me know if that did it!

Comment: Well tadman... I gave up on posting a multipart/form-data using node. I reluctantly put an input field of type file. Submitting with that input element works wonderfully. To be clear I'm not giving up :P, but I'm not spending another 8 hours until I get information from the guys who created the form-data module! At the end of the day it is abundantly clear that a file object needs to be sent across the network, not a buffer. No idea why / how they implemented it as a stream. Documentation should include how to receive the data.

Comment: The stream approach is usually better, it means you don't have to wait for the file to load before firing it into the request, but if it's not working that's annoying. Good luck!